# WhatsApp Battery Drain on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

Last night my iPhone XR battery completely drained over the course of 4 hours. It was due to WhatsApp Background activity, as shown in the animated gif below. (Click to view).

[image]

I've used WhatsApp for years and never had this problem before. In fact, I've never seen the battery drain so fast for any reason.

I'm running iOS 13.7.

I posted a message to WhatsApp help.

Please recommend options I have to avoid this. Thanks.

Also, if there is a better StackExchange community to post this, let me know.

Comment: It could be chat backup in progress, or just background refresh. Try turning on low power mode at night.

Comment: @anki I've added additional comments to (hopefully) make it clear that this is an unusual event, and far from any normal activity either with the phone or with WhatsApp.